# Which keyboard layout do I have?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout, layout

I bought a MacBook Air 13' and my keyboard layout doesn't match with any default input source.

This is my layout

[image]

At first, I searched which one would fit.

I found Spanish ISO but it doesn't appear on default sources. Then I read that changing idiom could fix that. Unfortunately neither.
Then I asked for help on BackMarket's costumer services (where I bought the laptop) and they send me the (supposedly) correct layout.

This is what they sent to me:

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't match a ****.

So here I am, I'm trying to learn how to program on python and I can't do it if I don't have a correct layout.

And that's it, I have no clue how to fix this and I would be so thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: It's standard Spanish, obviously (hint: It has the infamous "Ñ") . Searching for the serial number / service tag should confirm the original specifications

Comment: @Tetsujin - This is the Latin American variant: https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo:KB_Latin_American.svg Very little differences (e.g. "#" and "\"). So the OP's is the Macintosh specific variant of the standard European Spanish layout (I have 5 in front of me, I should know).

Comment: You're right, I don't know and don't care about Macs. Yes, there's a "<>" key, left of "Z", in one of mine (external, full keyboard). However, in a HP slim laptop (without keypad) that same key is at the right of AltGR. This key is above Enter and at the right of "Ç" in OP's photo. Different positions of one or few keys doesn't change the keyboard layout, as long as it/they is/are the exact same key or keys. Discussing thing in terms of "ISO" or "ANSI" (news to me, BTW, but indeed I use PCs) is confusing. In a nutshell, it's "Español" european what the OP should choose.

Comment: Again, this is specifically **AN** European Spanish layout. If it was Latin American "#" would be the secondary (+SHIFT) character, not the tertiary (+AltGr or Mac equivalent). And European stores don't carry products destined to the Americas markets and vice-versa (BackMarket.com or .es or .fr or .pt) is an European refurbished goods store. so yes, for them to confuse a spanish with a french keyboard is quite understandable but selling a Mexican/Chilean/Argentinian/etc. Mac is Spain is unheard of).

Comment: Unfortunately the only Macbook we have at the Spanish office right now has a Swedish keyboard so it won't help. Otherwise I would just post a picture showing it to be EXACTLY like the  OP's.

Comment: ANSI and ISOxxxx are character sets, NOT keyboard layouts (and there's no ANSI or ISO variants to select anyway in any OS). And unless you consider the functional keys as part of the layout there's indeed no difference between Macs and PCs. Unlike you that probably never used or even seen a Spanish keyboard, I have 5 nearby, all of them with the EXACT same layout (bar the special Mac keys) as the OP's. The Latin American variant is different as shown in the Wikipedia link above. **it couldn't be more clear**.

Comment: That some keys may appear in a different position as suggests by the schematics it doesn't matter, please understand this once and for all. What matters is one or more DIFFERENT keys like the one at the left of "1" which "ºª\" in Europe and something else altogether in Latin America. But the most telling feature is the absence of "Ç" in the Latin American variant. Reason being Spanish language doesn't use "Ç" but the character is there in the EUROPEAN Spanish keyboard because of other languages spoken in Spain that use it (Catalan, Portuguese, Asturian-leonese(?)).

Comment: @Tetsujin Unlike you, we're multinational, multilingual and we have to deal with lots of different keyboards from almost all over the world. With offices in Spain, Mexico, Colombia, Venezuela, Peru, Argentina... I think I know the differences between European and Latin american (again, here: https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo:KB_Latin_American.svg) Spanish keyboards. END OF STORY

Comment: I think I found the source of your confusion and a cursory explanation about the weird usage of norms and standards by Apple https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794 . The shape of the enter key as an identifier seems to be outdated or not applicable to small keyboards like the new ones in Mackbook 13". Yes, according to the article the OP's enter key suggests ANSI (as so wrongly used in this context) but in this case it isn't simply because there's **no Spanish ANSI**. "ANSI keyboards" are only the ones mentioned in the article and are for languages without special, accentuated, characters...

Comment: (...) For any other language that uses accentuated characters, its respective keyboard layout is "ISO", according to the Apple's scriptures. Now, this poorly translated post https://www.soydemac.com/en/Spanish-keyboard-or-Spanish-iso/ does indeed suggest there are 2 different layouts - "Spanish" for old keyboards and "Spanish ISO" for newer - but in any case this has absolutely nothing to do with the Latin American variant which, again, is very different in at least 4 keys. And no, the OP said "I found Spanish ISO but it doesn't appear on default sources" so **they didn't test it**.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Ye goddes but we went the hard way round to get there. I agree, you're right, it's a 'weird' layout of ISO. One I've never seen before… & I've used a lot of Spanish keyboards. Apple still calls that 'Spanish (Latin American)' on the KB you posted - which I'd already looked at. That page used to just have a picture of every single full keyboard, lots of them. They changed it to that version a couple of years ago.

Comment: Macs have at least two layouts for Spanish: one is called *Spanish - ISO*, and; the other is often called *Traditional Spanish*. I believe that the OP has the latter. See [Mac has wrong Spanish keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/q/424763/399707)