# Mac has wrong Spanish keyboard layout on Monterry

Tags: mac, keyboard-layout

I have the same problem as described on [Mac has wrong Spanish keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/questions/424763/mac-has-wrong-spanish-keyboard-layout)
I've been using spanish ISO keyboards on macs for 15 years and have always been able to select "Spanish ISO" option, but it seems that option is not present anymore in Monterry 14" M1 macbook pro. The only options are "Spanish", "Spanish - Legacy" and "Latin American". The [spanish keyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDiEd.png) differs from ISO in that the '<' symbol should be next to the z and not next to the 1 and also the symbols next to p and ñ are all different (and there are 4 keys in that region, not 3)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by removing `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` and then restarting the computer to make  Keyboard Setup Assistant pop out